# Windows 10 default applications shortcuts

Tags: windows, windows-10

I've noticed recently that shortcuts for default apps in Windows 10 (like Weather, OneNote, Edge etc.) are not stored in appropriate folders of task bar and start menu. I can see there shortcuts for non-default apps like in previous Windows versions. I tried looking for it in registry but failed.
Where can be those shortcuts found to be edited?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! I'm not really sure if you can change the shortcuts in Windows 10 (it's still missing some features). Maybe someone else here will know. But if there *isn't* an option for this, you can recommend it with the Windows Feedback App.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to locate them at least since I didn't find any method to achieve information whether they exist or not.